# How to insert inline content in a table cell without causing next tds to overlap the cell's content?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am using VueJS + TailwindCSS and, in one of my tables, I have the following layout:

```
...
<tr class="border-y border-gray-200">
  <td class="px-3 text-gray-500 whitespace-nowrap py-4 text-sm truncate">
    {{ row.name }}
  </td>
  <td class="px-3 text-gray-500 whitespace-nowrap py-4 text-sm truncate">
    {{ row.age }}
  </td>
  ...
  <td class="px-3 text-gray-500 whitespace-nowrap py-4 text-sm">
    <div class="flex">
      <div v-for="(language, index) in props.languages" :key="language"> 
        <img :src="`/img/flags/languages/${language}.png`" :alt="language" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="px-3 text-gray-500 whitespace-nowrap py-4 text-sm truncate">
    {{ row.description }}
  </td>
  ...
</tr>
...
```

This causes the `description` cell content to overlap `languages` flags whenever the viewport width is not enough. I have checked that the `flex` layout is causing it.

How to prevent this? Any ideas?
Or, in other words, how to insert inline content in table cells without losing its structure when changing viewport width?

Thanks in advance.